# Spring-Boot: Handle multiple requests concurrently

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using [Spring Boot to build a RESTful web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). My IDE is Eclipse Oxygen.

I send **multiple** HTTP get requests in **every 2 seconds** through **Chrome**, but they are triggered **one by one**. Each request will wait for the previous request to finish.

Here is my controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dummy")
public class DummyController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> dummytsp(@RequestParam(value="msg", defaultValue="Hello") String msg) {
        System.out.println("" + new Date() + ": ThreadId " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("message", msg);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My console out put is:

```
Thu Sep 14 11:31:15 EDT 2017: ThreadId 25
Thu Sep 14 11:31:20 EDT 2017: ThreadId 26
Thu Sep 14 11:31:25 EDT 2017: ThreadId 28
Thu Sep 14 11:31:30 EDT 2017: ThreadId 30
```

The console output shows that the controller is called **every 5 seconds**. But I'm sending the requests **every 2 seconds**.

How could I handle multiple incoming requests concurrently? (I should see the console output every 2 seconds)

**UPDATE**:

If I send requests in different browsers, it works perfectly.
If I test it in the same browser/application which shares the session, the problem will come out.

Is it possible to accept concurrent multiple requests from **same session**?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  By default Spring Boot web applications are multi-threaded and will handle multiple requests concurrently.  Are you using Embedded Tomcat?  Have you changed any of the default thread settings (e.g. `server.tomcat.max-threads`)?

Comment: @KyleAnderson the code works fine if I send the requests from different browsers. The problem shows up when I send the requests (open tabs) in the same browser. I updated my post pls check. ty!

Comment: This _might_ be a browser specific quirk.  On Windows 10, Chrome & Firefox do seem to queue multiple requests to the same URL, while IE, Edge, & curl do not.

Comment: @KyleAnderson yes you are right. I am using chrome which gives me the problem, but curl & works fine. Do you mind to put your comment as answer so that I could accept your answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default Spring Boot web applications are multi-threaded and will handle multiple requests concurrently.

This might be a browser specific quirk. On Windows 10, Chrome & Firefox do seem to queue multiple requests to the same URL, while IE, Edge, & curl do not.

Comment: Hi @Kyle Anderson So i don't need to used Executor or Thread explicitely

Comment: How to handle 1000+ request at the same time? Supposing that the service only returns "hello world" and doesn't do any other processing? I tried changing supposedly default max threads from 200 to 800+ but TPS will not increase, thank you.