# What could be causing Spring Boot server to process requests two at a time?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, server

I have a simple Spring Boot REST server which I intend to use for load testing modules under development.

Under moderate loads, the clients were experiencing prolonged delays, even timeouts. It turns out that the server was only processing 2 requests at a time.

This has nothing to do with *server.tomcat.max-threads*.  The worker thread pool (*http-nio-< port>-exec-< number>*) never exceeded 10 when I increased max-threads above 10, but shrank to 1 when set to 1. I assume because the pool did not receive more than the two requests at a time.

What could be limiting the number of concurrent requests to 2 ?

Comment: Do you send your requests from the same browser? If so, read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223363/spring-boot-handle-multiple-requests-concurrently?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. Although I was using multiple browsers, turned out the scheduling in the controller I use had a problem.  Once fixed, I got and processed multiple, simultaneous requests.